# How do I make an extension out of a module I've created in opencart 3.x?

Tags: opencart-3, opencart-module

I've already created an module in my opencart 3.0.3.2 for a friend referral process. Now I want to make that into an extension to install/uninstall whenever required. I'd be greateful if someone tell files or functions or modifications I need to make in the overall directories to make it an extension. Sorry I'm a beginner to web dev and opencart.

I've referred some guides but they give the complete tutorial for building module along with extension.

Comment: You just need to find in OC marketplace some free extension, and just study it. You'll find the answer to your question. Here short instruction: http://dejanjanosevic.info/ocmod-quick-install-guide/

Comment: thanks. will look into it.